# App terminates on back button

Tags: iphone, xcode, ios7, crash

I have a view controller "Gallery screen" namely, as user taps button "Gallery" it goes to that view controller. Now I have a web service call if any picture of particular outlet exists fetch it or else if it doesn't exist then show an AlertView saying "No image found". Now my problem is when user go to gallery screen if there is no image of that outlet and user hits back button before response of service "no image found" app terminates. I get that popup saying "no image found" on previous screen that i get after pressing back button as i "Ok" it, it terminates but THIS ONLY HAPPENS IN iOS 7. Please help and thanks in advance.

EDIT:
I have also tried to dealloc my objects but still the same issue. May be I'm missing something here is the code that I used.

```
-(void)dealloc
{
    bllGalleryImages.delegate = nil;
    bllGalleryImages = nil;
}
```

here is my viewDidLoad Method

```
-(void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];

progress = [[MBProgressHUD alloc] init];
progress.labelText = @"Loading";
[progress showUsingAnimation:YES];
[self.view addSubview:progress];

scrl = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 100, 300, 300)];
scrl.scrollEnabled = YES;
scrl.minimumZoomScale=1.0;
scrl.maximumZoomScale=4.0;
scrl.delegate=self;

// Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.

}
```

here is my View will appear method

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
   [self userInterface];
   [self callService];
}
```

here is my callService method

```
-(void)callService
{
NSMutableDictionary *param = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
[param setObject:@"xyz" forKey:@"DeveloperKey"];
[param setObject:outletObjForInfo.outlet_id forKey:@"outletID"];

bllGalleryImages = [[BLLAuthentication alloc] init];
bllGalleryImages.delegate = self;
[bllGalleryImages getGalleryImages:param];
}
```

Comment: check your dealloc method your any variable or object not release 2 times .

Comment: Exactly this is the issue but I think I'm missing something i tried to dealloc it but again same termination

Comment: -(void)dealloc
{
    bllGalleryImages.delegate = nil;
    bllGalleryImages = nil;
}
this is what i have tried but still the same

Comment: check your viewdidunload and check there one variable 2 times released .

Comment: you have not any require galleryimage delegate = nil .

Comment: Add a breakpoint to dealloc. Is it even called? If not, you got a retain-cycle somewhere - e.g. strong reference in a delegate.

Comment: Are you canceling the connection?

Comment: Please check my edited version of question where i have also provided some code may be it helps you more to understand

Comment: you will check your viewdidunload method ?

Comment: Im not canceling connection i just press back button and it takes me to previous view controller and then i get a response msg of no image found.. and it terminates

Comment: I have not checked my viewdidunload method, do i need to make one

Comment: @user3422986 you will send code in mail ???

Comment: ya sure your id please

Comment: @user3422986 you send your full code .

Comment: Sorry its little confidential, I sent you entire view controller h, m and nib file. I think solution would be in those files :)

Comment: @user3422986 but i can't able to run that file's and check what's problem .

Comment: I can understand that but never mind, if you find any solution from available material I will work around at my end then

Comment: @user3422986 ok it's all right. i will check that files and if i get any problem solution so i can tell you .

Comment: @Till I have checked via break points it has been called